# NSMutableArray Comparison

Tags: iphone, objective-c, collections, nsmutablearray, foundation

I have two `NSMutableArray`s. One array consists of records from the database and the other array consists of records from webservices.

I want to compare each record from the database array to each record in the web services array using a unique key like `barcodeID`. Also, if the `barcodeID` key is same then I want to remove the item from the array. It's like I'm updating my database records. If we get the same records from the webservice then I don't want to insert them.

Please help me I'm unable to break the logic for this.

Answer (score 5):

if `Product.barcodeID` uniquely identifies your objects, then you can use that member to implement `-[Product hash]` and `-[Product isEqual:]`.

then you can easily use `Product` in `NSSet`s. `NSSet` and `NSMutableSet` contain several methods to combine and remove sets.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force method of doing such comparison is for every record in one array is checked with every record in another. If you find it then stop and discard the object. if you do not find it, then you add it to the array. This of course will have a very high time complexity with a worse case scenario is O(n^2). you could shorten this down by using certain data structures inside your database and web service. Maybe storing them in sorted order or through some algorithm.

You should do some research yourself before asking this question. I shall leave you the option to find a way to optimize your code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of the idea of the brute force method. As mentioned above this is incredibly slow compared to alternatives.

```
- (void)myUpdateFunction
{
    NSMutableArray *baseDatabaseArray;
    NSMutableArray *baseWebServiceArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < baseWebServiceArray.count; i++) {
        id value = [[baseWebServiceArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"barcodeID"];
        NSArray *array = [baseDatabaseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"barcodeID = %@", value]];
        if (array.count > 0)
        {
            id obj = [array objectAtIndex:0];
            [baseDatabaseArray removeObject:obj];
        }
        [baseDatabaseArray addObject:[baseWebServiceArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

I have been using [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) and love it.
You have to be using Core Data for this though. Here is what my update code looks like with Magical Record.

```
- (void)updateDatabase
{
    Class class = NSClassFromString(self.managedObjectClassName);

    if ([class MR_countOfEntities] > 0) {
        for (NSArray *array in self.totalBatches) {
            [class MR_updateFromArray:array];
        }
    } else {
        for (NSArray *array in self.totalBatches) {
            [class MR_importFromArray:array];
        }
    }

    [self.totalBatches removeAllObjects];
}
```

If you have any questions about Core Data feel or if you need me to walk through the algorithms feel free to ask.